# How to set value for raddropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am trying to set value to raddropdownlist using javascript but getting select is undefined.

```
   var dropdownlist = $find("<%= rcbLayout.ClientID %>");
   var item = dropdownlist.findItemByText(rlvControllers._dataSource[itemIndex].FORMLAYOUT);
   item.select();
```

markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="LayoutLabel" runat="server" Text="Form Layout:"></asp:Label>
<telerik:RadDropDownList RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="rcbLayout" Width="250px" DataTextField="TEXT" DataValueField="VALUE" runat="server"></telerik:RadDropDownList>
```

Comment: Is that `dropdownlist` contains `undefined`? I don't know what `$find` does, usually in jQuery `$("<%= rcbLayout.ClientID %>")` is used for dropdownlist selector.

Comment: Actually showing item is null.

Comment: Use the DevTools HTML inspector to find the item ID and compare it with the value returned by rlvControllers._dataSource[itemIndex].FORMLAYOUT.
Check this blog post of how to inspect the generated HTML by the control - https://www.telerik.com/blogs/improve-your-debugging-skills-with-chrome-devtools#inspect-the-generated-html-of-a-control